# No visible @interface error, UITableView and registerClass

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I'm new to Objective-C/Xcode, so bear with me.

I'm trying to implement a TableView, where each cell contains another View, similar to the Master-Detail template. I'm following a book that teaches doing it from scratch (in other words, without the Interface Builder).

Things seemed to be going fine until I got to the viewDidLoad method:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

The book tells me to insert this code, right before the end curly brace:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdent];
```

along with a static variable, before the @implementation:

```
static NSString *CellIdent = @"Cell";
```

However, here's my problem: when I try to type "registerClass", the UITableView class does not seem to contain that method. I followed this documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITableView which says that the method is indeed part of that class, but Xcode doesn't seem to recognize it. I wonder if it's a syntax problem, but I have not been able to find any part of the code that doesn't work (I even copy-pasted the same line of code from other tutorials, just to be sure).

If I had to guess, I'd say I'm somehow implementing the UITableView class wrong, but I haven't been able to figure out what the problem is. Help?

The precise error that is thrown is, "no visible @interface for 'UITableView' declares the selector 'registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier' which keeps me from running the project. Although I searched for this error across the board and none seemed to relate to the problem I keep having.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: 4.4.1. I have a lot of extra frameworks and kits installed too.

Comment: 4.4.1 won't cut it, needs to be 4.5+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the most up-to-date version of Xcode and are targeting iOS 6.0 or above  - this is a method that was added in iOS 6.0

Click on the project, then under Summary look for Deployment Target and check the version number.

Answer (score 0):

registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: is available in iOS 6.0 or later, probably you select earlier iOS version as target in your application.

Always check witch iOS version methods belong to.